# Calling a Restful API with POST data

Tags: php, rest, curl, restful-authentication

I am trying to call my own Restful API with POST data; but it does not work ! Could you please let me know if I am missing something here?

My code in login.php:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
$UN = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['user']));
$PWD = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES));

$data = array('action' => 'authenticateUser',
    'username'=>$UN,
    'password'=>$PWD
        ); 


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'my URL goes Here'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

and now in index:

```
    //The following require once echo the response from my restful API( I am not sure why it does echo though!) :[{"username":"John Smith","password":"*32ewrer43","firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith"}
    require_once('includes/login.php');

    $response = json_decode($response);
    //The following line echo int(1) ! so why not my data?!
    var_dump($response);
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly does not work? What errors are you getting? http://php.net/curl_error

Comment: I'm so sorry! I just updated my question! Could you please help me why var_dump($response); is not printing my data!

Comment: There is no error! but no data either!

Comment: You need `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

Comment: oh man you solved it! Thank you so much

Comment: No problem. I guess you *could* consider deleting this question, as it's unlikely to benefit future generations (if you want).